# BotFramework (Node, Facebook) - Cancel prompt when receiving Postback

Tags: node.js, facebook, botframework

Is there a way to cancel a pending prompt.text when the user, on the facebook channel, on nodejs, presses on a button already in the chat, that sends a postback?

The result is that the prompt stays active, waiting for input. It just sends out "I didn't understand. Please try again." after answering to the postback.

The prompt code is:

```
builder.Prompts.text(session, "What do you want me to search for?");
```

And the button code is:

```
session.endDialog(new builder.Message(session)
    .attachments(attachments));
  });

let attachments = [new builder.HeroCard(session)
.title(cardInfo.name)
.buttons([
    builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "searchDialog", "", "Go On")
])]
```

Comment: Can you post your code that is causing the issue?

Comment: I have edited the question with samples